# What is the time complexity for iterating through a map in nested for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I know the map in C++ is a balanced binary search tree. But, when I iterate through the map in nested for loop, I wonder what the time complexity would be

```
for (auto x : mp) {
        for (auto y : mp) {
              //
              //
        }
 }
```

Comment: If there are no breaks, then it will be the product of those complexities. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Quimby, I know traversing through a map is just performing an inorder traversal on it. Inorder traversal time complexity is O(n). We're doing the inorder traversal twice. That's why I thought the complexity would be O(n ^ 2). But I'm not sure if I'm correct

Comment: the question boils down to: What is the time complexity of incrementing a maps iterator. I don't know what it is, but lets say it is `X` then total is `O( n * (X +  n*X))`

Comment: @NaveenKumar Yes, it should be that in general, but C++ compiler is free to optimize, it can reorder the loops if it can prove it won't change the outcome. So, it really depends on what you do with the loops - empty loops are likely to be optimized away, independent loops can be pushed up.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard requires that forward iterators are amortized constant time, so each of your loops are Theta(n). Because they're nested, the complexity will be Theta(n^2).

If you have a (balanced or not) binary search tree with parent links, then incrementing an iterator is O(log n) in the worst case, but O(1) amortized over the whole tree iteration, because each node in the traversal is visited at most 3 times (once when you first encounter the node, once after traversing the left subtree below it, and once after traversing the right subtree below it).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the implementation of the iterator of `mp`. Every for-loop creates one iterator instance, but in the background they could rely on the same objects.

In the most and simple cases,  it will be outer over inner loop, so easily O(n²).

In a strange case it might be O(n) but then the implementation of the iterator is messed by logic (maybe someone can comment a good reason)

And in a even stranger case it doesn't determine, when the first iterator is disturbed by the creation of the next one. The main reason there would be lazy static loop variables or static pointer used in the iterators class.

And to your special case when the elements are only available as a binary tree, think about how an iterator there will work: next() will be either left, right or none(=backwards up), so a fixed search length with the maximum recursive tree length. Balanced means there is in general a set of l/r and at the tip log(n) elements of none, regarding this as a constant factor meaning n*=n x log(n). So the expected answer is O( (n*log(n))² ) = O( n² * log(n)² ) and regarding what outruns the Landau is the first part, so again O(n²) when it comes to the relevant number of elements.

Even then it may be performance wise to check the inner structure of map and create an iterator based on the keys, not on map.get().

Comment: How can it be O(n)? Can you expand on it? If you print each `(x,y)`, there will be O(n^2) of them.

Comment: The iterators next() could be a static object inside the iterators class, so then after the first inner iteration is done, the outer loop checks also with hasNext() and sees that nothing is left and will finish also. As I said, I can't imagine a propper use-case, and so I asked if someone could give a good example.

Comment: I do not think that would constitute a valid implementation. That is suggesting iterating over two independent structures would not be possible which it certainly must be.

Comment: But the example iterates inner and outer on the same structure. And thats the handle that delivers the iterator.  I've not said that it might be valid but possible. There might be all kinds of crazy things that can be build around that. Think of schedulers, stacks and event systems. Not that this will be a proper way, but possible.

Comment: I think see what you mean. Still, STL iterators must be independent of each other, so it I'm pretty sure it is not allowed. But as an optimization for some niche custom structures sure, it could help.